# Running commands in bash and updating tkinter.Text in a python GUI

Tags: python, bash, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a Python GUI application in Tkinter that's supposed to run a list of commands in bash. I also want to update the user on what task is running and whether or not it finished successfuly.
The way I have it set up right now is simillar to this:

```
import tkinter
from time import sleep

class mainApp(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        # Set up a simple gui
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # Text box with messages for the user
        self.textBox = tkinter.Text(master = parent)
        self.textBox.pack()

        # Button to run the test
        self.commandButton = tkinter.Button(master = parent,text = "Run test", command = self.doCommand)
        self.commandButton.pack()

    def doCommand(self):
        # The command also creates the list it's supposed to run. Commands themselves run qiime2 (a program that runs in bash)
        listOfCommands = ["command1", "command2","command3"]
        for command in listOfCommands:
            self.textBox.insert(tkinter.END, "Running: {}\n".format(command))
            #subprocess.run(command.split())
            sleep(5)
            self.textBox.insert(tkinter.END, "Finished. \n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    mainApp(root).pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = True)
    root.mainloop()
```

- The sequence of events that I wanted was:

  1. The textBox gets updated with "Running: command"
  2. The command is run in bash using subprocess (in the example I'm just using sleep as a placeholder)
  3. Once the command finishes, the textBox gets updated with "Finished"

  - repeat for all commands in list

What actually happens is the GUI freezes, commands run in the background in bash and once the last one is finished then the textBox gets updated with all messages at once.
I'd really appreciate any help. I tried a bunch of different things, like making the subprocess run in a generator or a coroutine, I also tried threading (but admittedly I don't fully understand it so I may have done it wrong) and the results didn't change.

**UPDATE**: changing `process = subprocess.run` to `process = subprocess.Popen`, running `self.textBox.update_idletasks()` before and `process.communicate()` after `process` seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: While the program is running `sleep(5)` (or something else) it can't update the GUI so the window becomes unresponsive. Try using `process = subprocess.Popen(...)` then `is_proc_done = (process.poll() is not None)`

Comment: The simple way is to add `self.textBox.update_idletasks()` before executing the command.

Comment: Both of those solution have the same effect which is inverting the previous problem - now the textBox gets updated first with all three messages at once and the commands run in background. I want the messages to update once the command finishes in bash.